# How can I differentiate between polysaccharide bands and protein bands on SDS-PAGE?

Tags: proteins, microbiology, gel-electrophoresis, sds-page

I tried to extract bacterial polysaccharide but after running a SDS-PAGE I couldn't differentiate between the polysaccharide band and protein ones. I face a problem of moving up of the samples from the will and no clear bands. Any suggestions?